# It's possible to retrigger workItemHandler in JBPM 6.2 from subProcess handling error

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

It's possible to retrigger or send signal like 'retry', 'repeat' workItemHandler in jBPM's process ?

I have process with some workItemHandler and some of them throw exception and I use SignallingTaskHandlerDecorator for wrap exception and send signal for 'ErrorHandling' subProcess.

From a subProcess I want to reinvoke workItemHandler's executeWorkItem method.

I found class which can help new DefaultWorkItemManager().retryWorkItem(workItemID) but I have problem with  create instance of DefaultWorkItemManger in WorkItemHandler class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution by the creation of custom abstract class for my workItem's. Abstract class implements WorkItemHandler interface.

Similar job made magnolia team with creation of AsyncWorkItemHandler

```
public abstract class AsyncWorkItemHandler implements WorkItemHandler
```

For some further information visit:

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Custom+tasks